# Static field initialization sequence in a class

Tags: java, static

I'm having trouble understanding initialization order when a class has a static instance of itself. Also, why this behavior seems to be different for a `String`.

Please see the following example:

```
public class StaticCheck {
    private static StaticCheck INSTANCE = new StaticCheck();    

    private static final List<String> list =
        new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("hello"));
    private static final Map<String, String> map =
        new HashMap<String, String>();  
    private static final  String name = "hello";

    public static StaticCheck getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private StaticCheck() {
        load();     
    }

    private void load() {
        if(list != null) {
            System.out.println("list is nonnull");
        } else {
            System.out.println("List is null");
        }
        if(name != null) {
            System.out.println("name is nonnull");
        } else {
            System.out.println("name is null");
        }
        if(map != null) {
            System.out.println("Map is nonnull");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Map is null");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StaticCheck check = StaticCheck.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
List is null
name is nonnull
Map is null
```

I am absolutely not clear on why the field `name` is not null.
Static fields are initialized in the following cases as mentioned under Class initialization:
http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/07/when-class-loading-initialization-java-example.html

Looking into the above example, my thoughts:

1. As said, static fields are initialized before instance initialization in Java. Here, when I am invoking the static method `getInstance()`, it will lead to class initialization which implies initialization of static fields. In this case, the fields `map` and and `list` shouldn't be null.
2. In the above example, since the field `INSTANCE` is static, its object initialization takes place and its constructor calls `load()` when other fields were not initialized. Because of this the fields `list` and `map` are null. So then why did `name` get initialized? I am a little confused.

Comment: To give you a hint, that article you linked to says *"Classes are initialized from top to bottom so field declared on top initialized before field declared in bottom"*. This is important to the behavior of your example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constant `static` variables are initialized before any non-`static` variables are initialized.  The [JLS, Section 12.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2), states the initialization procedure for a class:

> 6. Otherwise, record the fact that initialization of the Class object for C is in progress by the current thread, and release LC.
>      Then, initialize the static fields of C which are constant variables (§4.12.4, §8.3.2, §9.3.1).
>
> (other steps here)
>
> 9. Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface, in textual order, as though they were a single block.

So, `INSTANCE` is listed textually first, before `list`, `map`, and `name`.  Why aren't all 3 still `null`?  This is because `name` is initialized by a *constant expression*; it is a *constant variable*.  It is initialized first, before `INSTANCE`, because it it a constant variable.

Note that you can move the line initializing `INSTANCE` after `list` and `map`, causing `list` and `map` to be initialized before `INSTANCE`.

Answer (score 7):

The `String` type `name` variable is a compile time constant, which are inlined by the compiler at compile time. So, the condition:

```
if (name != null)
```

after compilation will become:

```
if ("hello" != null)
```

which is of course true.

As for why `map` and `list` are `null`, that's because, when the class is initialized, `INSTANCE` field is initialized, calling the constructor, which in turn calls the `load()` method. Note that, by this time, the other `static` initializers has not yet been run. So, `map` and `list` are still `null`. So, printing them in `load()` method will be `null`.

Comment: Could you extend your answer to the first part of the question as well? May be not so obvious at first glance.

Comment: @Turing85 Added explanation for that.

Answer (score 1):

Only primitive types and `String` will be assigned at compile time, and only if the field is `final` and initialited with a literal or constant expression. All the other `static` fields and blocks will be evaluated later, sequentially. See this example:

```java
public class StaticExample {

    private static StaticExample instance1 = new StaticExample(1);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new StaticExample(3);
    }

    public static boolean b = true;

    public static final boolean fb = true;

    public static Boolean B = true;

    public static final Boolean fB = true;

    public static String S = "text";

    public static final String fS = "text";

    public static final String cS = "te" + "xt"; // constant expression

    public static final String xS = fS.substring(0, 2) + fS.substring(2, 4);

    private static StaticExample instance2 = new StaticExample(2);

    private StaticExample(int no) {
        System.out.println("## " + no + ": ##");
        System.out.println(" b: " + b);
        System.out.println("fb: " + fb);
        System.out.println(" B: " + B);
        System.out.println("fB: " + fB);
        System.out.println(" S: " + S);
        System.out.println("fS: " + fS);
        System.out.println("cS: " + cS);
        System.out.println("xS: " + xS);
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
## 1: ##
 b: false
fb: true
 B: null
fB: null
 S: null
fS: text
cS: text
xS: null

## 2: ##
 b: true
fb: true
 B: true
fB: true
 S: text
fS: text
cS: text
xS: text

## 3: ##
 b: true
fb: true
 B: true
fB: true
 S: text
fS: text
cS: text
xS: text
```

`fb` is a final primitive, `fS` and `cS` are constant final String, only this three fields are preassigned.